# Tableau String to Date Time Format Issues

Tags: date, format, tableau-api

I am pulling in date information via MySQL and the date is in the string format of "MM/dd/YY hh:mm:ss"

Using the built in conversion to date isnt working; so I tried using DATEPARSE and also using DATE and manually parsing it. I have had no luck and I have no idea why I keep getting "null" as the answer or it is putting the month as year, day as month, and year as day.

See screenshots below for the different formulas I have used:

[DATEPARSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78xbn.jpg)

[Original date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9byJH.jpg)

[DATE with manual parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpxAA.jpg)

Comment: why are you using yyyy in your formula instead of yy?

Comment: That particular screenshot was one of the many variations I tested, using y, yy, yyyy, Y, YY, YYYY none of those variations worked

Comment: The date format strings are defined here http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Comment: Thanks! I did try that website previously to craft my calculation however it was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me using your example original data

```
DATEPARSE('mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss',[Time] )
```

I used [tableau's documentation](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dates_custom_date_formats.html) of custom date formats to find the right formula for the format.

If this doesn't solve the problem then it is most likely due to a Locale issue. The Dateparse function relies on the locale specified by your computer settings to interpret and then display the strings you want to convert and can affect whether a certain format can be specified. This means that if a certain format is not recognised it will return a null. This will often occur is the windows region and language format is changed to another language other than the original language the workbook was created it.

So check your locale and if required execute the following workaround (documented by tableau [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/158230)):

1. Open Windows control panel > region and language > format
2. Click format dropdown and change to original language of workbook creation
3. click ok or apply and reopen tableau work book

Comment: I tried that and still have the "null" result. I then changed my data source to extract and not live, and it seemed to have worked. I didnt read anywhere that you had to have a data extract for it to work but I guess that might be the problem.

Comment: Can you provide any further details/ data? I used one of your provided examples "11/05/17 10:09:21" and parsed it using the formula I posted and I had success.

Comment: I am pulling in the data from MySQL via MongoDB BI connector: Python runs a program, writes into MongoDB, the connector pulls data from MongoDB into Tableau based on MySQL connection. I dont want to post the actual dataset here as it could be a little sensitive, sorry.

Comment: No all good, just wanting to understand why Tableau isn't treating it like the mock up data I have created. Is there the potential for the string to have any leading or trailing whitespace or any text encoding ?

Comment: What is the Locale on your computer ? I am thinking it could be the issue listed here have a look under local considerations https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/data_dateparse.html and see a documented workaround here https://community.tableau.com/thread/158230

Comment: Wow! @SMB that appeared to be the answer, I forced tableau to be English (US) instead of the default. So I didnt change my computer Locale but I changed the Tableau workbook locale.

Comment: Just another update after playing with the data a bit; the data conversion is very unstable. Between changing the locale and flipping from live to extract data I can usually get it to work; but every-time I open the workbook the date seems to get messed up again. Thanks to all for the help, I think I can make it work but its a bit unsettling it doesn't seem like it is truly solved.